# ¿Puedo cambiar las url que forma la extensión better blog de magento 2?

Tags: php, url, magento2

En mi proyecto instalé la extensión del better blog de magneto2 , pero me di cuenta de que las url que forma son así 'dominio/blog/post/name_post'
y yo las quiero así 'dominio/blog/id_post/name_post'. Gracias

Comment: ¿id_post en vez de post?

Comment: Si el id del post que estes viendo, así es dinámico y genera diferentes urls para el SEO